# What exactly happens when a header file is included?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have two doubts:

1. What does a header file actually contain? All the function definitions or only the prototype declarations?
2. What happens when I include a header file? Are all the contents of the header file attached to my code? Or is it that the specific (or all) contents of header file is loaded into the memory and the functions are called according to my code?

Comment: It is copy-pasted in the exactly point that you write the #include line.

Comment: "What does a header file actually contain?" -- Try looking at it.

Comment: @JimBalter: Do you have any advice for how to find and look at it? It's not immediately obvious how to do so.

Comment: There are millions of C header files available on the web, just a couple of clicks away, as well as in most textbooks on the language. Googling "example C header file" brings up plenty of information. I urge you to develop *basic*, *fundamental* intellectual skills if you have any hope or plans on becoming a programmer. Asking questions on SO won't make up for their lack.

Comment: Here's one useful result from the above google search: http://web.stanford.edu/~fringer/teaching/operating_systems_03/handouts/lecture8.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C and C++ are languages, which extensively uses feature called **function forwarding**. This means, that you can say, for instance:

```
void f(int i); /* note the semicolon */
```

This means: "I promise, that somewhere later in the source code someone will define, what the function f actually does". After such *forward*, you may use this function as it really existed and compiler will require someone to actually define this function later (if there is no definition, compilation will fail). This forward is called also a header, because it actually is a header of function definition:

```
void f(int i) /* Header */
/* Body */
{   
    /* ... */
}
```

Header file is a file, which contains mostly such forwards. You can use the header file to get access to functions defined somewhere else (for example in different compilation unit or external library) and then attach required object files or libraries to provide implementation of these header files. Apart from function forwards, in a header file you may also find structure definitions, constants or other items, which are required for proper use of defined functions.

How compiler matches your forward to actual implementation in .c file? Well simply - *by the header*. It attempts to find a function definition (implementation), which exactly matches the header you declared earlier.

What happens if you `#include` header file is that compiler (specifically, the preprocessor) copies the whole contents of header file into place, where you put your `#include`. That's all magic, nothing more happens.

During runtime, the header file does not matter at all, because your executable file consists only of executable code. Compiler either loads all functions available in the library (which is accessed by the header file) or (mostly probably, if optimization is turned on) chooses only these functions, which you actually used in your code.

The funny thing is, that compiler requires function definition (implementation) only if someone actually uses that function. Otherwise, the forward is ignored. Try:

```
void f(int i);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    /* Do not use f here */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Header file is a file, which contains mostly such forwards. " -- Well, no. Many if not most header files contain structs, typedefs, macros, constants, etc., in addition to function prototypes.

Comment: "During runtime, the header file does not matter at all, because your executable file consists only of executable code." -- Headers can include executable code, esp. inline functions. Saying the header doesn't matter at runtime is like saying the source file doesn't matter at runtime ... it's technically true but pointless.

Comment: @JimBalter From the question I got an impression (maybe wrong), that OP thinks, that header files are being loaded into memory during runtime - thus my answer.

Comment: @JimBalter "Apart from function forwards, in a header file you may also find structure definitions, constants or other items, which are required for proper use of defined functions.". When I think about it a little more, header consisting only of constants and structs isn't very useful until you provide a function, which can use them. Macros are a different story though. I write in C++, but from my experience most headers had mainly functions/classes and - as an addition - structures, constants, macros etc.

Comment: "When I think about it a little more, header consisting only of constants and structs isn't very useful until you provide a function, which can use them." -- You should try thinking even more. Some header files have the sole purpose of defining a specific data type (struct). This being C and not object-oriented, the functions that operate on that data type may well not be "members" of the data type and so they occur in other headers. But my point was that your answer is too heavily focused on prototypes, whereas C headers are much broader in their scope of use.

Comment: @JimBalter In the beginning, OP asked question about headers in the perspective of functions, so I wrote the answer in this context. I mean, to use all those structs in one header, you will have to include other header with functions anyway (at least that was point of that part of answer).

Comment: The OP asked what a header file actually contains. Since the OP knows so little about header files, a good answer would educate broadly. "you will have to include other header with functions anyway" -- not relevant, but also not true ... the functions that use the struct may all be local/static. The C standard itself specifies a number of header files with no function prototypes -- assert.h, ctype.h, errno.h, stdarg.h, stdbool.h, etc.

Answer (score 7):

**What does a header file actually contain? All the function definitions or only the prototype declarations?**

Header file contain function declarations, extern variables,macros,structures etc. Best practice is to keep Function definition is in `.c` file.

**What happens when I include a header file? Are all the contents of the header file attached to my code? Or is it that the specific (or all) contents of header file is loaded into the memory and the functions are called according to my code?**

Header files are nothing more than inserting the contents of them at the place where you use `#include`. You can write all that on your own if you want to.

Including a header file is equal to copying the content of the header file but we do not do it because it will be very much error-prone and it is not a good idea to copy the content of header file in the source files, specially if we have multiple source file comprising our program.

**Edit:**

For memory layout of complete execution of program you can follow this link http://fgiasson.com/articles/memorylayout.txt

Comment: Okay. But then where is the .c file? How will the compiler know that and use the function? How is the function definition brought into memory for execution?

Comment: "But then where is the .c file?" -- On your disk somewhere. "How will the compiler know that" -- because you tell it the name of the source file. "and use the function" -- compilers don't use functions, they generate code that calls functions. "How is the function definition brought into memory for execution?" -- Function definitions are not brought into memory and are not executed ... *code* is brought into memory, including all the code the compiler generates to implement your functions.

Answer (score 2):

1. The header file should contain useful declarations of functions (and perhaps variables) and definitions of types (`struct`, `union`, `enum` or `typedef`) and macros (function-like or object-like macros).  These typically declare the facilities made available by some part of some library.  The standard headers, such as `<stdio.h>`, describe portions of the standard library, for example.  Modern headers might contain `inline` function definitions, but otherwise, a header should define neither functions nor variables — it should only declare them.

   Note, too, that a public header should normally only declare types and functions that are useful to the consumers of the source code.  It should only include other headers that provide declarations that are necessary to make use of the facilities in the header; it should not (usually) include extraneous headers that are only needed by the implementation of the facilities described by the header.
2. The contents of the header file (and any header files it includes) are copied into the translation unit (TU).  The `#define` macros and conditional processing (`#if` etc) are noted.  You can usually find a way to see the output of the preprocessor on a given source file to see what the C compiler proper actually sees (but beware; it can be very verbose).  For example, the options are often `-E` (required by POSIX for the [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html) command) or `-P` (an older commonly used option).

The TU is what the compiler proper sees.  It contains the source code from your file plus the relevant information from the headers you include.

Comment: (1) should include macros and constants.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note, it may be obvious...

- ad 2/ If you #include a file the #include directive in the includig
  file is repalced by the included file. This is what happens. This is
  what the preprocessor does. By defintition
- ad 1/ A header file can continue anything (anything the compiler can
  accept). Other answers describe the usual conventions used to
  organize code between c and h files, but these are only conventions.
  They are very good to stick with, you are likely to get lost with a
  bigger project if you dont.

Actually, if you write c for a very simple microcontroller, you may make it completly without header files and their including.

If you are a student/hobyist/have the time, it may be useful, to run the prepprocessor separately have a look on the itermediate output.
Fun fact: Long time ago i used to use the c preprocesor to generate coustomized letters.

Anyway my point is: **what c preporocesor does is defined by standard, while orgainizing code between files a convention which you/your team can select to a certain extent.** This distinction is important.